# How do I resolve a path relative to an ASP.NET MVC 4 application root?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I resolve paths relative to an ASP.NET MVC 4 application's root directory? That is, I want to open files belonging to the application from controller actions, referenced like `~/Data/data.html`. These paths are typically specified in `Web.config`.

**EDIT:**

By 'resolve' I mean to transform a path relative to the application's root directory to an absolute path, .e.g. `~/Data/data.html` → `C:\App\Data\Data.html`.

Comment: That is how you get 'reference' those files from root...

Comment: @Nate What do you mean, that the ~ gets expanded automatically?

Comment: [HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) ?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "resolve".  You want to send a file to the user?  You want to reference an image or css file in an element in your page?  You want create a link to the file?

Comment: @aknuds1 - That doesn't help.  For what PURPOSE are you trying to do this?

Comment: @MystereMan The file is only to be read on the server, it doesn't really matter though as I'm only interested in getting the absolute path name... That should be enough to define the scope of the problem.

Comment: Ah ok so you want to get the Absolute path to the App_Data folder?

Comment: @aknuds - You want Server.MapPath then.

Comment: @Nate Yes, unless there's some more idiomatic/automatic way to expand paths specified in Web.config relative to application root.

Comment: Yea you would use MapPath (see answer) that will give you the Absolute path.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

To get the absolute path use this:

```
String path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/data.html");
```

EDIT:

To get the Controller's Context remove `.Current` from the above line. By using `HttpContext` by itself it's easier to Test because it's based on the Controller's Context therefore more localized.

I realize now that I dislike how `Server.MapPath` works (internally eventually calls `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`) So I now recommend to always use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` because its static and not dependent on the context unless of course you want that...

Comment: I just want to read the file on the server, it's not to be returned to the client.

Comment: This is the way to do it. Also, if you need to use this statically, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795986/using-server-mappath-inside-a-static-field-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I'm in a non-static method of a System.Web.Mvc.Controller subclass, but `HttpContext` has no property `Current`. What's up?

Comment: Replace `Current` with `ApplicationInstance`

Comment: It seems to me I can user `HttpContext` instead of `HttpContext.Current` as it is a `Controller` instance property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785413/difference-between-httpcontext-current-and-controller-context-in-mvc-asp-net.

Comment: Yes you can if you want the Context of the Controller and not the application.

Comment: From what I understand it's typically preferable to use the `HttpContext` property as it can be mocked when testing, want to update your answer as such? It works at least.

Answer (score 64):

I find this code useful when I need a path outside of a controller, such as when I'm initializing components in Global.asax.cs:

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Data/data.html")
```

Comment: HostingEnvironment.MapPath is a better answer.  When you execute the code outside the context of a http request then HttpContext.Current is null  and your code crashes.   HostingEnvironment.MapPath always works.

Comment: That is also worth mentioning that "HostingEnvironment.MapPath" can be customized if you have your own implementation of a Virtual Path Provider. Works in any "hosted" environment (windows service or iis hosted) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/910441

Answer (score 15):

Just use the following

```
Server.MapPath("~/Data/data.html")
```

Answer (score 4):

In the action you can call:

```
this.Request.PhysicalPath
```

that returns the physical path in reference to the current controller. If you only need the root path call:

```
this.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller use:

```
var path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Data/data.html");
```

This allows you to test the controller with Moq like so:

```
var queryString = new NameValueCollection();
var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
mockRequest.Setup(r => r.QueryString).Returns(queryString);
var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
mockHttpContext.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(mockRequest.Object);
var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
server.Setup(m => m.MapPath("~/Data/data.html")).Returns("path/to/test/data");
mockHttpContext.Setup(m => m.Server).Returns(server.Object);
var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
mockControllerContext.Setup(c => c.HttpContext).Returns(mockHttpContext.Object);
var controller = new MyTestController();
controller.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;
```