# Get MVC application's absolute path like http://foo.com/bar/gar from a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

From within an external class library, I'd like to convert a path like so:

**~/bar/gar**

to a path like so:

**http://foo.com/bar/gar**

This is an ASP.NET MVC application.

Since we're not in a view, I cannot use the `UrlHelper` class from within my external class library. That's because that class is an instance class and it does not have a default, parameterless constructor. It needs an instance of `System.Web.Routing.RequestContext`.

Another option I tried was:

```
var absoluteRedirectUri = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility
                     .ToAbsolute(settings.Parameters.RedirectUri.Value, 
                     HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
```

But that still yields **/bar/gar** instead of **http://foo.com/bar/gar**.

Comment: Does this help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239006/how-do-i-resolve-a-path-relative-to-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application-root

Comment: No. That's not my question. `Server.MapPath` yields the path of the file on the hard drive of the server. I am after completing a simple content path with the domain name. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public string FullyQualifiedApplicationPath
{
  get
  {
    //Return variable declaration
    string appPath = null;

    //Getting the current context of HTTP request
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    //Checking the current context content
    if (context != null)
    {
      //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
      appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
        context.Request.Url.Scheme,
        context.Request.Url.Host,
        context.Request.Url.Port == 80
          ? string.Empty : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port,
        context.Request.ApplicationPath);
    }
    if (!appPath.EndsWith("/"))
      appPath += "/";
    return appPath;
  }
}
```

Here is the [**link**](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/get-absolut-url-of-asp-net-application/) where you can read in detail.