# Microsoft Graph API email attachment

Tags: c#, email, email-attachments, microsoft-graph-api

I currently have a slight issue with attaching a word document to an email message in the Graph API.

I can send the email absolutely fine if i point the path to the location on the server, however as theres the possibility this may change, i want to use a copy which is held within the project structure in /Content/Docs/File.docx. However if i use the path `~/Content/Docs/File.docx` it looks for the file in the IIS directory of Program Files. If i remove the `~` then it looks for the content directory in the C:/ drive. Does anybody know how i can get around this and use a version of the file within the application?

My code is below:

```
using(var msg = new MailMessage())
{
      msg.Subject = string.Format("This is the subject");
      msg.Body = string.Format("This is the message body");
      msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("~/Content/Docs/File.docx"));
      await SendMessage(msg, emailAddress);
}
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239006/how-do-i-resolve-a-path-relative-to-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application-root
Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: That worked. thanks. so simple. if you want to put it as an answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Edgaras pointed out, using `Server.MapPath` to get a fully-qualified path will help you here.