# Can't access to HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I can't access to HttpContext.Current on my project MVC4 with C#4.5

I've added my reference to System.Web in my project and added the using instruction on my controller page...

But I can access currentHandler only...

```
var context = HttpContext.CurrentHandler; //Current
```

Is `HttpContext.Current` deprecated on C#4.5 ?

I've looked this help page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx

Comment: you added reference to your project, but have you got a `using System.Web` on top of your file ?

Comment: if anyone find you can't use `HttpContext.Current.Request` or `Request.ApplicationPath`, try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;`

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Have you included the `System.Web` assembly in the application?

```
using System.Web;
```

If not, try specifying the `System.Web` namespace, for example:

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current
```

Comment: funny but it only worked for me after adding the full System.Web.HttpContext.Current didn't pick up the using, i wonder why

Comment: @CMS, I think it may have something to do with Extensions.

Comment: @CMS It's pretty old but I think it's because there's some using in the Controller that already implements HttpContext

Answer (score 39):

This is because you are referring to property of controller named `HttpContext`. To access the current context use full class name:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current
```

However this is highly not recommended to access context like this in ASP.NET MVC, so yes, you can think of `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` as being deprecated inside ASP.NET MVC. The correct way to access current context is

```
this.ControllerContext.HttpContext
```

or if you are inside a Controller, just use member

```
this.HttpContext
```

Comment: Thanks for explain, but i can't access Current, just CurrentHanlder ... so don't resolve my problem...

Answer (score 8):

Adding a bit to mitigate the confusion here. Even though Darren Davies' (accepted) answer is more straight forward, I think Andrei's answer is a better approach for **MVC** applications.

The answer from Andrei means that you can use `HttpContext` just as you would use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`. For example, if you want to do this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

you should instead do this:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

Both achieve the same result, but (again) in terms of **MVC**, the latter is more recommended.

Another good and also straight forward information regarding this matter can be found here: [Difference between HttpContext.Current and Controller.Context in MVC ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785413/difference-between-httpcontext-current-and-controller-context-in-mvc-asp-net).

Comment: That really does clarify Andrei's answer. Thanks for this.