# How to pass credentials from PowerShell and retrieve in API method

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core-mvc, credentials

I have an API method like this

```
[HttpGet]
public string UpdateComputerDescriptions()
{
    var cred = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    UpdateDescriptionsAndTimestamp(System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
    return "done";
}
```

And I've tried to call it from PowerShell with

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password, $domain)
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString($url)
```

And

```
Invoke-WebRequest $url -Credential $creds
```

My problem is that I need to pass the `$creds` credentials to my `UpdateDescrptionsAndTimestamp` method.

However, when I check `DefaultCredentials` and `DefaultNetworkCredentials` objects in the API method, they don't contain any values (I'm expecting to see at least the username in there).

I even tried changing the signature to `public string UpdateComputerDescriptions(NetworkCredential credential)`

and calling with

```
Invoke-WebRequest $url -Body @{credential=$creds} -Credential $creds
```

But I get the same result.

How can I achieve this?

**Note** I do not want to pass in plain text (or - for that matter - encrypted) credentials, as the powershell script will eventually be run as the user and I'll just pass in the default credentials. I just need to know how I can retrieve this from inside the API

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've gotten to work in the past (passing the creds through the Authorization header as Base64 encoded string:

**C#**

```
HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
string authHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
    throw new Exception("The authorization header is empty or isn't Basic.");
string encodedCredentials = authHeader.Substring("Basic".Length).Trim();
string credentialPair = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedCredentials));
var credentials = credentialPair.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var username = credentials[0];
var password = credentials[1];
```

**Powershell**

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$url = "yourUrl"
$credentials = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($username + ":" + $password))
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $credentials"}
```

However, you'd likely be better off creating a system for token based authentication ([see link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661090/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-without-any-user-interface))

**EDIT for further explanation**

in depth look at an example C# controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Application.Controllers
{
    public class GetDataController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            var user = AuthUser(HttpContext.Current);

            var dataset = new List<string>();
            // code to populate dataset

            return dataset;
        }

        //** I would put this somewhere else in your application so you can reuse it **\\
        private static User AuthUser(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var authHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
                throw new Exception("The authorization header is empty or isn't Basic.");
            var encodedCredentials = authHeader.Substring("Basic".Length).Trim();
            var credentialPair = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedCredentials));
            var credentials = credentialPair.Split(new[] {":"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
            var username = credentials[0];
            var password = credentials[1];

            var user = new User();
            // code to validate login & populate user model

            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to install the WebApi package.
In the Nuget Package Manager Console: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi`

Comment: JED I just get `'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [DSSTools]` on that first C# line

Comment: Okay so I need to change that to just use static `HttpContext.Request.Headers`, but now for some reason the header comes through as `negotiate` and not `authorize`, probably because I have the `[authorize]` attribute on the controller

Comment: You need to include the system.web namespace. There is also system.web.mvc.httpcontext, but that's not what you want. [See post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309239/cant-access-to-httpcontext-current)