# How to access HttpContext from controller in ASP.NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

In asp.net how do i get the current httpcontext for the page that i am on?

i have tried giving the relevant controller the httpcontext as an argument, but this does not work. I have found plenty of people describing how to specify the object , but i simply cannot find any info on how the httpcontext should be added to the controller (like, in a argument or so)

this does not work

```
    public class MovieController : Controller
    {
            public ActionResult Random(HttpContext mycontext)
        {

            RandomMovieViewmodel rmvm = new RandomMovieViewmodel();


            return View(rmvm);
        }
```

How do i acces the context? should I maybe make a attribute?

Comment: *should I maybe make a attribute?* why? Did you checked your class base properties in the documentation?

Comment: hmm, checking the documentation of httpcontext?

Comment: ASP.NET covers a lot of stacks - WebForms, MVC, Web API, ASP.NET Core. All of them have a Context in one way or another. None of them passes it as an action parameter. Which stack are you asking about?

Comment: *hmm, checking the documentation of httpcontext?* are you extending your class from which contains `Random` method from `HttpContext` or rather `Controller` ?

Comment: im on asp.net mvc

Comment: Selvin: no this is my controller, the random() method is the method that a certain url routes to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access to HttpContext.Current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309239/cant-access-to-httpcontext-current)

Comment: TAHA SULTAN TEMURI: i did see that one before posting. But as I wrote i my question, this question does not talk about how exactly the httpcontext ends up in the controller, only which kind of object is used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller definition is really important here.

For example, in .Net Core 2.2 with a Controller derived from ControllerBase, HttpContext exposed as a property.

I'm not sure about your environment or your class definition, but it always similar in Asp.Net MVC. Just make sure that, you defined your Controller class correctly.

**UPDATE**

When you derived from Controller class, HttpContext exposed as property. You can directly use it.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var context = HttpContext;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: im on asp.net mvc. im not completely sure what controller class definition is, but im following a course, and everything should be fine.

Comment: But the thing im asking about is whether anyone knows how to acces the httpcontext object for that page? is it a question that makes sense? can i do it with the parameter?

Comment: Can you share more detail of your Controller definition? If you can update your question with sample code that will be more easy to understand the problem.

Comment: im really quite confused what is meant by controller definition? is it the routing from url to controller?

Comment: In the question you paste you method (action) definition which should be reside in a Controller class. It should be something like `public class TestController : ControllerBase`

Comment: ahh, i see my controller class derives from controller. will update. thank you