# Set session for each user identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've got a simple page `View` in ASP.NET MVC with

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["User"].ToString() @DateTime.Now
```

I simply want to programmatically set the user's identity so that when I re-navigate to this page or any other I can get the current user identity.

Also when navigate new User I need create a new User identity.

This is the controller

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var pModel = new PModel
    {
        Countries = PopulateDropDown(" SELECT ... ")
    };

    HttpContext.Session["User"] = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    HttpContext.Session.Timeout = 300;

    return View(pModel);
}
```

This is the value printed on the page `View` if I'm connected to app from desktop pc

```
myDomain\myUser 22/01/2021 19:53:15
```

Now I have tried connected to app from my mobile device with new user and the value printed on the page `View` is

```
myDomain\myUser2 22/01/2021 20:04:37
```

But when refresh the browser on my desktop pc value printed on the page `View` is changed to

```
myDomain\myUser2 22/01/2021 20:08:25
```

The user `myUser2` replaced on the app the first connected user `myUser`

The same happens if I move in reverse, that is mobile device vs desktop pc...

Are there special considerations for this?

In the ASP.NET MVC project using without problem... for each user I have the corresponding Session without replace user...

I don't understand this problem in my ASP.NET MVC application... I'm sorry...

```
public static string tUser
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["tUser"] != null)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["tUser"].ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["tUser"] = value;
    }
}
```

**Update #1**

[image]

**Update #2**

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 300;

    var pModel = new PModel
    {
        Countries = PopulateDropDown(" SELECT ... ")
    };

    return View(pModel);
}
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current - that's in your second code block and not the first. You want that "Current"  `HttpContext.Session["User"] = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();`

Comment: I think you need the Current in your other spot too `HttpContext.Session`

Comment: @Nikki9696 Thank you for reply. Please see **Update #1** on the first question... can't add the `Current` to  `HttpContext.Session `

Comment: using System.Web - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309239/cant-access-to-httpcontext-current/18309281  Note: the answer shows a better way to get to it also. I'm just used to Current  =)  I'm not sure that's the issue though, looking through that thread.

Comment: What happens if you remove that outputcache attribute? It has vary by param, but there's no params passed, so I'm not sure how that might affect things.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Please see **Update #2** on the first question. I have changed the `controller` without success. The user `myUser2` replaced on the app the first connected user `myUser` and viceversa...

Comment: From update #2 - you removed this entire line? `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]`

Comment: @Nikki9696 Many thanks for this help. I have removed the line` [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]` and now the user is not replaced!!!

Comment: @Nikki9696 Many thanks for this help. I have removed the line `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]` and now the user is not replaced!!!